# Javascript history api - window.history.forward() availability

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, html5-history

I have some back/next buttons set up for a phonegap app built in angular.js.

I'm using partials in angular for the pages and using window.history as some simple back/next buttons. All is working good but I'd like to add some visual feedback as to when the back and next functionality becomes available.

Is there a way to check if the history.forward is available?
the next page wont be known, so I dont think looking through the pages in the history is a viable solution to this, it shouldnt kneed to know what page its on or what pages the app contains, something like (sudo)

```
if(window.history.forward()){
  // show buttons as available
}else{
  // show buttons as not available
}
```

Sadly history only returns undefined, but is there any other way?

Any suggestions would be great

thanks

Comment: Check `history.forward` specification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`history` doesn't allow this, still you can get `history.length` to check if there is history at all (if not - just disable both buttons).

Or you can "dirtyhack" it by wrapping the whole site or app with 100% width|height borderless iframe on your "index" page and log this iframe's hisory "manually" from the top window (not advised at all; will work for the same domain only; will not work with "X-Frame-Options:DENY" on your server).